# What makes a site feel heavy when scrolling?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm just finishing up, built my first website, but the problem is it feels heavy, i.e., scrolling up or down feels like, choppy. The page loads initially quite decent (5 secs), but once you're there it feels very similar to theblaze.com in terms of heaviness.

What is it that makes a site feel heavy, and what are the troubleshooting steps to figure out what the causes are? It's an html site with a few jquery plugins. I've googled around for "heavy site", "choppy scrolling", etc., but not much has come up, other than the usual "lazyload your images" or whatever. (I'm doing that.) Most people seem concerned about initial loading speed, but not the feel of the scrolling once you're on the site.

What are the likely culprits?

To me it feels like a memory thing. Like when you have photoshop open and the computer starts to lag.

Comment: Too much whisky does it to me every time.

Comment: Do you have some functionality bound to the `$(window).scroll()` event? That could be the cause of the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, apart of the tools mentioned, the process to find the problem is quite easy;

- check the size of the page, including images
- remove any script and "feel" the page, if still heavy, the problem is something else, if it feels right, then the problem is/are the script(s)
- if the problem is the script, start by moving it to the bottom of the page
- if still affects, check that it works properly
- if without the script is too heavy, try to reduce the amount and size of images
- if you use tables, try to set dimensions
- try to avoid nested tables or many nested divs, that takes some rendering time.
- scrolling and refreshing effects are heavy on the rendering engine of the browser.

Check all that and then check for specific solutions for the right problem.

Bye

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the [Google Page speed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights): , it will list all of the pitfallss your site is having and at the time will suggest ways for you to improve on them.

Google will rate your site in terms of performance on Mobile and Desktop. If you get a score of around 90+, you should think that you have done  a great Job.

Comment: @Gabber: you might be interested in this too
https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/speedtracer/

Comment: Yes! I used this http://jsperf.com/ and this http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/ to do some website testing, but now my tools seem just like a good complement for google's. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like processing delays within your browser - it might make sense to watch CPU/ mem usage as you scroll. You could try removing elements one at a time to find the culprit.

I've noticed this sort of lag when asking the browser to resize images rather than doing it in advance.

Comment: I'll look into all of these, thanks everyone. PageSpeed score in the low 90's. Anyway I installed Google Speedtracer, but dammit... as usual, I don't understand most of the google developer tools. Their explanations read like you work for Google and know everything already. So I'll keep an eye on this thread in case others post more things I can try, I have loads of free time to devote to this.